# Solr-Lucene Support multiple language tokens in same field

Tags: solr, lucene, cjk

We work in the proxy business, for our customer, where to achieve certain business need,  we change some field information and send it to the Solr (version 5.5.4). Below are the configurations of Solr schema.xml for a particular field at Solr side.

```
<fieldType name="text_general_no_norm" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

As I discussed above,  in some special case, we have a situation where these fields ( field1, field2  etc..) value can be in CJK pattern. That means  field1, field2 store plain **English text** or **CJK text**. Hence, in case of choosing StandardTokenizer, while indexing/query it works fine when it has to deal with plain English text, whereas in the case of CJK text it doesn't work appropriately.

When we index a CJK text with the current configuration, it breaks each character (Sometimes it pairs multiple characters also) and index it. As an example
if we index a text

field1: "맯뭕禪玸킆諘叜葸", according to **StandardTokenizer** logic it breaks into 
  맯          뭕     禪玸     킆諘     叜    葸 and index in it.

Later, when we search on the same field with the similar text - 
q : field1: "맯뭕禪玸킆諘叜葸", it gives the result along with it more irrelevant result also. Our assumption is, when Lucene breaks and build multiple tokens for querying, it performs OR operation with all tokens. Hence, Any single token  from (맯     OR     뭕  OR    禪玸  OR    킆諘  OR   叜  OR   葸) will present any record, it will return that record as a result.

We also tried **LetterTokenizer**, but it doesn't behave same as like **StandardTokenizer** in many cases. We also tried **Copy field** options, but it is also not feasible as the application layer is not so flexible to determine CJK token and change the query at runtime.

Please suggest any approach for indexing or querying, so that we could filter irrelevant results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this post will be useful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108688/solr-multilingual-indexing-with-one-field.
He should solve your problem, but I do not know what disadvantages of this solution.